# Find an object properties by searching for keys by a string, and if one is true, return as true

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I want to go through an Object and search for a key with a string. I want the ablity to look to see if there more then one key with the string.

So if I have a string "started_on" then I want to search property named "started_on" and another one name "started_on&format", I want to go to see if either has "2013-Mar-03", and if one does, return as true

I been using Lodash a lot and I feel like there a way to do it, but I'm coming up with nothing so far. If anyone know a way to search by key, at least, I can start least play around with it more.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but objects keys are unique

Comment: I want to do more of a filter out the properties by their key,

So, filter out the keys that "includes" a string

Comment: Hi Branderson

As I understood the question , please find below the way you can start thinking in the direction of the solution and the achieve your scenario. 
Object.keys(obj).filter(ele => {  if(ele.indexOf('started_on')!=-1) {
      result.push(ele);}})  . If you print the result , you will see the array of the object keys matching your given string. Hope this helps!

Comment: I woudl do that without lodash. `if (obj["started_on"] === "2013-Mar-03" || obj["started_on&format"] === "2013-Mar-03") { return true } else { return false }`

Comment: I need the string to be a parameter, so I can't used the literal strings

Comment: Object.keys(obj).filter(ele => { if(ele.indexOf('string_parameter_here')!=-1) { result.push(ele);}})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const obj = {...};  
let string = "started_on";  
let valueToMatch = "2013-Mar-03"; 

const result = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key.includes(string)).some(key => obj[key] === valueToMatch)

console.log(result) // <== will be true if any key with string "started_on" has value "2013-Mar-03"
```

Comment: Welcome! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do?

```
function findMatchingKeysWithValue(
  keysToMatch: string, 
  valueToMatch: string, 
  obj: {[key: string]: any}): string[] {
  return Object.keys(obj)
   .filter(key => key.startsWith(toMatch))
   .filter(key => obj[key] === valueToMatch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myObj = { a: 'bu', b: 'mu', c: 'bubu' }
const filtredKeys = Object.entries(myObj).filter(e => e[1].contains("bu")).map(e => e[0])
 output => ["a", "c"]
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: I understood that it should be part of the value, not the key. Now I see that it's wrong and one wants to find all keys that content some pattern. Never mind Idea remain the same, it's possible to use Object.keys.filter instead

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.